# C# List - Remove duplicates

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates

I have a list that look like this:

```
U-70754, U-70755
U-70754, U-70755
U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788
U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788
U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788
U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788
```

I looking for a way to remove duplicates, and rearrange the list so the list will look like this:

```
U-70754
U-70755
U-70786
U-70787
U-70788
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around this issue, I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these strings? If so, just use [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay Enumerable.Distinct will only check the whole item, not the individuel items that are seperated by comma

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski unfortunately not, again this solution does not remove the each seperated item (comma seperated)

Comment: @NicklasChristensen please, share your code then and how the item is represented

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski look in the question, it cannot be more clear how it is presented, and how I want it to be presented

Comment: @NicklasChristensen So it is actually a single string? Your question in not clear **at all**, hence all the comments.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first item in the list is `U-70754, U-70755`, that's 1 item? not 2?

Comment: You will have to split the comma-separated items into individual items, and then you can run distinct on them.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen correct

Comment: Is each line an element in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split every item by comma, map the result into one sequence using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___), then use `Distinct` method to get a unique values

```cs
var list = new List<string>
{
    "U-70754, U-70755",
    "U-70754, U-70755",
    "U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788",
    "U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788",
    "U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788",
    "U-70754, U-70755, U-70786, U-70787, U-70788"
};

var result = list.SelectMany(i => i.Split(new [] { ',' })).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: Note that split will split on the commas, as instructed, but the items after the commas will start with a space, so you probably need to take that into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the structure of your list correctly, it looks like each item can contain several comma-separated strings.  If that's the case, you can get what you're looking for with a few extra lines:

```
var filteredList = list.SelectMany(x => x.Split(","))
                       .Select(x => x.Trim())
                       .Distinct()
                       .OrderBy(x => x);
```

[Here's a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BvvBey) showing it in action.

**EDIT**: I see Pavel beat me to the punch with essentially the same answer, but this code `Trim`s the Split strings (without which they won't sort correctly) and then explicitly orders them since `Distinct` will most likely only preserve the original order.